# How to make a sticky drop-down menu with a transparent dropdown background while hovering a button?

Tags: html, css

I have managed to combine some code and styling to produce a drop-down menu, that sticks to the upper part of the page when scrolling down. When I hover a button of the menu, most of the functionality I want is there: a block of sub-buttons in a different color pops-up and when I hover them, they change their color. However what I don't want is the whole navbar (menu) to increase it's height downwards proportionally to the amount of sub-buttons, that have dropped down.[image]

[image]

As you can see the whole menu extends downwards. I want only the sub-buttons to dropdown (the white ones, not the darkness around them)
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Chart.js</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background:  #ff9933;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 45px;

}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: sticky;

}

/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {   
  -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: #fff9e6;
  padding: 20px;
}

.a {
    background-color: #000000
}


/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Chart.js</h1>
  <img src="https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg" alt="Logo" style="width:320px;height:240px;">
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="./Chartjs-main.html">Въведение</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#footer" class="right">За мен</a>
</div>




<div class="row">
  <div class="main">
    <h1 id="Intro">Въведение</h1>
    <h2>Какво са Chart.js</h2>
    <hr> <br>
    <p>Прости, но гъвкави JavaScript графи за дизайнери и разработчици</p>
    <p>Chart.js е библиотека на JavaScript, която ви позволява да рисувате различни видове диаграми, като използвате елемента на платното HTML5. Тъй като използва платно, трябва да включите полифил, за да поддържате по-стари браузъри.</p>
    <br>

    <h2 id="Installation">Инсталация</h2>
    <hr> <br>
    <p>Chart.js може да бъде инсталиран чрез <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js">npm</a> или <a href="https://libraries.io/bower/chartjs">bower</a>. Препоръчително е да получите Chart.js по този начин.</p>
    <p> При инсталацията се стига през CLI до папката на проекта и се изпълнява следната команда: <a style="bold:true; color: red">npm install chart.js --save</a>  за NPM и <a style="bold:true; color: red">bower install chart.js --save за bower.</a></p>
    <p>Chart.js поддържа Line, (хоризонтална и вертикална) Bar, Radar, Polar, Area, Pie и Donut диаграми, отзивчив е и предоставя опции за разширяване на тези типове диаграми и писане на нови.</p>
    <br>

    <h1 id="Integration">Интеграция</h1>
    <hr> <br>
    <p>Chart.js може да бъде интегриран с обикновен JavaScript или с различни модулни товарачи. Примерите по-долу показват как да зареждате Chart.js</p>
    <br>

    <h2 id="Tags">Тагове за включване</h2>
    <hr> <br>
    <p>&lt;script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<br>
&lt;script&gt;<br>
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...}); <br>
&lt;/script&gt;</p>
    <p>За да върви кода нататък, нужно е да бъде добавен първия ред горе, като path/to/ заменим с директорията където е инсталиран Chart.js </p>
    <br>
    <p>
         &lt;canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"&gt;&lt;/canvas&gt;
         <br>&lt;script&gt;
         <br>var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
         <br>var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         <br>    type: 'bar',
         <br>    data: {
         <br>        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
         <br>        datasets: [{
         <br>            label: '# of Votes',
         <br>            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
         <br>            backgroundColor: [
         <br>                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
         <br>                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
         <br>                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
         <br>                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
         <br>                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
         <br>                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
         <br>            ],
         <br>            borderColor: [
         <br>                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
         <br>                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
         <br>                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
         <br>                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
         <br>                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
         <br>                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
         <br>            ],
         <br>            borderWidth: 1


         <br>        }]
         <br>    },
         <br>    options: {
         <br>        scales: {
         <br>            yAxes: [{
         <br>                ticks: {
         <br>                    beginAtZero: true
         <br>                }
         <br>            }]
         <br>        }
         <br>    }
         <br>});
         <br>&lt;/script&gt;
         <br>


    <p>


    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script src="./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>

        <script>

         var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
             type: 'bar', data: { 
             labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{ label: '# of Votes', data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [ 
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)' 
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)', 
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)', 
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)' 
            ],
            borderWidth: 1 
            }] 
        },
         options: { scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero: true } }] } } }); 
        </script> 

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Default</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><code>duration</code></td>
        <td><code>number</code></td>
        <td><code>1000</code></td>
        <td>The number of milliseconds an animation takes.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><code>easing</code></td>
        <td><code>string</code></td>
        <td><code>'easeOutQuart'</code></td>
        <td>Easing function to use. 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><code>onProgress</code></td>
        <td><code>function</code></td>
        <td><code>null</code></td>
        <td>Callback called on each step of an animation. 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><code>onComplete</code></td>
        <td><code>function</code></td>
        <td><code>null</code></td>
        <td>Callback called at the end of an animation.</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer" id="footer">
  <h2>ФН:81477     e-mail: mister.senko@abv.bg</h2>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update these codes and it should work:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top:100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

**Note:** you should avoid using overflow: hidden while working on dropdown.

**Demo:**
https://codepen.io/Bibeva/pen/rNadyPR

Answer (score 0):

pls try this. i change some code

**css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background:  #ff9933;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 45px;

}

.navbar {

  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:46px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;

position: absolute;

background-color:
#f9f9f9;

min-width: 160px;

box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px
rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

z-index: 999;

left: 0;

top: 47px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;

}

/* Column container */
.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
/* Sidebar/left column */
.side {
  -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Main column */
.main {   
  -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 70%;
  background-color: #fff9e6;
  padding: 20px;
}

.a {
    background-color: #000000
}


/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```